# Good Example .Net Open Source Solution Using a Composite UI

Tags: .net, open-source, prism, architecture

I'm learning about composite UIs at the moment and I wondered if anyone could recommend a good open source project that utilises a composite UI that I could take a look at?

I've got the Prism framework and have gone through the samples. I'm looking for an actual project that has used them in a non-sample application.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I have edited your question with info re. Prism.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Composite"?  Do you just mean in a general sense?

Comment: This link nicely describes it... http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/PRISM   - "Complex client applications containing lots of graphical interfaces need to be constructed from various component blocks, perhaps developed by separate teams, and assembled together like a giant puzzle. Such an application has what is called a "Composite UI"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks.Show is a to-do app written by PixelLab with an amazing UI. It uses Prism v4. It is technically a "reference" app to show off WPF features, but it isn't a trivial sample.

Here it is on Github:
https://github.com/thinkpixellab/Tasks.Show